# Master and slave bind DNS servers with different version

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, master-slave

I am having issues with my master-slave setup, so I'm trying to release what is an causing troubles.
Master is running on CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) and using BIND 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.1 (Extended Support Version).
Slave is running on CentOS release 5.11 (Final) and using BIND 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-25.P1.el5_11.5.
Could be a problem if bind versions are not the same?

Comment: Do you've got problems or is this just theoretical? For me at least this is quite unclear at the moment, I've flagged your question appropriately.

Comment: I am having an issues, my slave doesn't resolve queries when master is down. I cannot find in theory are the master and slave versions have to be the same.

Comment: So...please provide the configs and logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal protocol BIND (and other name servers) use to transfer zone data between servers is AXFR, which has been standardized since RFC 1034. It's difficult to imagine BIND getting it wrong at this point in time, and if they were to do so it would get noticed very widely very quickly. The problem is almost certainly to do with the configuration of your servers rather than the software versions.